# prime that does not divide $2^{n}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does there exist a prime number $p$ that does not divide $2^{n}-1$ for any natural number $n$?

Comment: Well, $2$.   Otherwise no, by Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: I assume , $0$ is not a natural number here, otherwise we could choose $n=0$ and every $p$ would divide $2^n-1$

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is an odd prime, there is always a number $k$, such that $2^k\equiv 1^\mod p$

In particular, you can choose $k$ as the order of $2$ modulo $p$

If we assume $n>0$, of course $2$ does not divide $2^n-1$ for any $n$

Comment: Instead of the order, you can (following lulu's hint) choose $p-1$ because we have $2^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$ for every odd $p$ (For some $p$, the order modulo $2$ actually is $p-1$, and the order always divides $p-1$)

Answer (score 0):

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}2{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I didn't know that $1$-character answers are admissible.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Well, the answer isn't actually $1$ character long (Try to edit it). Nevertheless, I do not understand the upvote, although the answer is actually correct.

Comment: If you look at the source, you'll see the answer contains 8 times `{}` both before and after the $2$.

Comment: @Henrik That doesn't make it a good answer, with or without $2\times$ {}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}.

Comment: I never claimed that, I was just trying to explain how he got away with a 1-character answer.